# Parameters of class constructor

Tags: typescript

When working with libraries I often need to get type of one of props. While this is quite straightforward with functional components:

```
function Test(props: {a: number}) {
  return props.a;
}

type A = Parameters<typeof Test>[0]["a"];
```

I cannot figure out how to get the same for class components.

Let's take a simple class for example:

```
class Test {
  a: number

  constructor(a: number) {
    this.a = a
  }
}
```

I tried:

```
type A = Parameters<typeof Test.constructor>[0] 
\\ Error: Type 'Function' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.

type A = Parameters<typeof Test["constructor"]>[0]
\\ Error: Type 'Function' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the built-in utility type [`ConstructorParameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype) instead.

```
type A = ConstructorParameters<typeof Test>[0]
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeBYAUNaYBc0AdgK4C2ARvAE5ZY7AD2hyVxwSDVAFPkWZVQCUaOjmhIAFgEsIAOjDQAvLlEBfLOsxYkATwAO8aAEEl0AMJMWbDlQAKYKmFLwk1CAB5dBhgDM4iJAA+AG0ABgBdWi1MIA)